# finding the maximum subsequence of string?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming. I have been struggling with this programme for a long time.
Question:
what logic error am I having with my code?

Problem:
need to find the maximum subsequence of a string. The length of the required subsequence, and the content of the string are from input.
for example, maximum subsequence with length 3 of string "abcde" is "cde".
the subsequence retrieved should have the same order as the original string

EDIT: A subsequence is a subset of the input string "I" arranged in the original order.

The maximum subsequence in this question is the largest one (in alphabetical order) of those subsequences with length K.

For instance, why in the case `AbCd687fs` `4` the subsequence is not"bdfs" but "d8fs"? The reason is that "d8fs" is larger than "bdfs" in alphabetical order

for `1265432` `2`. You can get some subsequence with length 2, e.g., 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 65, 64, 63,62,54,... . And in alphabetical order, the subsequence "65" is the maximum.

For `AbCd687fs` `4`. You can get some subsequence with length 4, e.g., AbCd, AbC6, bCd6, bC8s,d687, d87f, d8fs, d7fs,... . And in alphabetical order, the subsequence " d8fs" is the maximum.

My approach:

1. initialize `string buffer` with same length of `I`, filled with `'*'` : `string buffer(I.length(),'*')`
2. inner for loop to find the largest character in string `I`
3. replace the character into the `string buffer` with the same index position of the character in `string I`
4. remove the current largest character in string `I`. Then go through the for loop again to find the next largest character in string `I`.
5. while loop with number of iterations same as value of `K` to run the for loop `K` times
6. When the while loop ends, remove all the `'*'` from string buffer. The remaining content should be the maximum subsequence only.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string I;
    cout << "Please input a string:" << endl;
    cin >> I;

    int K;
    cout << "Please input the length of subsequence:" << endl;
    cin >> K;

    string buffer(I.length(), '*');
    int pos;

    while (K>0)
    {
        char vMax = I[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < I.length(); i++)
        {
            if (I[i] > vMax)
            {
                vMax = I[i];
            }
        }
        pos = I.find(vMax);
        //buffer.insert(pos, I, pos, 1);
        buffer.replace(pos, 1, I, pos, 1);
        I.erase(remove(I.begin(), I.end(), vMax), I.end());
        K--;
    }
    buffer.erase(remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '*'), buffer.end());

    cout << "The maximum subsequence is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << buffer[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "maximum subsequence of a string"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry for being unclear, just edited the problem description

Comment: What is expected outputs for data: `cabe` `2`, `cacbc` `3`, `aba` `2`?

Comment: @MarekR
`cabe` `2`: `ce`;  
`cacbc` `3` : `ccc`;  
`aba` `2` : `ba`

Comment: Why `ba` not `ab` in last example?

Comment: @TedLyngmo
According to the test case `12345898` `2`. The expected output is `98` instead of `89`. So I guess the test case assumes that the output should give the larger character first, and followed by the smaller one if it is the case with this kind of format `aba` `2` : `ba`

Comment: @TedLyngmo so assume only one of them could be correct. And that should be `ba`

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate that the subsequence does not need to be contiguous; and to clarify what its being "maximum" means, since I still don't get it.

Comment: @einpoklum I have edited the problem description. It should be much more clearer now.
The maximum subsequence in this question is the largest one (in alphabetical order) of those subsequences with length K.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have edited the problem description. It should be much more clearer now.
The maximum subsequence in this question is the largest one (in alphabetical order) of those subsequences with length K.

Comment: @chengraphael Aha, ok, that's a lot different. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code has a big problem since you erase characters from `I` and therefore can't calculate the `pos` in the original string properly.

I suggest that you use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to get an iterator to the `char` with the largest value instead of doing the search manually.

Here's how to fix it using `AbCd687fs` `4` as an example:

- Search for the `char` with the largest value in the range `AbCd68` (`7fs` not included because we must be able to find `4` characters in total). `d` is found.
- Search the range `687` (`AbCd` and `fs` are not included), `8` is found.
- Search the range `7f` (`AbCd68` and `s` are not included). `f` is found.
- Search the range `s` (`AbCd687f` are not included). `s` is found.

Implemented:

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::max_element
#include <iterator>   // std::prev

std::string get_substr(const std::string& I, size_t K) {
    std::string buffer;
    buffer.reserve(K);

    for(auto maxit = I.begin(); K --> 0; ++maxit) {
        maxit = std::max_element(maxit, std::prev(I.end(), K));
        buffer += *maxit;        
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/58jPdvY74)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fW9WhMr9z correct answer should be `56` and complexity is `O(n^k)`

Comment: @MarekR Why should it be 56? 62 is the greater substring according to OP:s requirements.

Comment: `5` and `6` are two greatest digits in this string, they should be selected and order should be conserved. Maybe this example will be more clear: https://godbolt.org/z/h1YvYjovh

Comment: @MarekR Yes, that's how I interpreted it at first too, but then OP clarified it. The example `AbCd687fs` `4` should for example return  `d8fs` and not  `bdfs` which my earlier solution returned - and [yours too](https://godbolt.org/z/rezcEE6aM) I see.

Comment: @MarekR Should we clean up these comments or do you still see issues / wrong answers coming from the code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I made modifications to your code and this should most probably help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string I;
    cout << "Please input a string:" << endl;
    cin >> I;

    int K;
    cout << "Please input the length of subsequence:" << endl;
    cin >> K;

    string buffer(I.length(), '*');
    int pos;

    while (K>0)
    {
        char vMax = I[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < I.length(); i++)
        {
            if (I[i] > vMax)
            {
                vMax = I[i];
            }
        }
        pos = I.find(vMax);
        //buffer.insert(pos, I, pos, 1);
        buffer.at(pos) = vMax;
        I.at(pos) = ' '; //Space has the least ascii value in printable characters
        //buffer.replace(pos, 1, I, pos, 1);
        //I.erase(remove(I.begin(), I.end(), vMax), I.end());
        K--;
    }
    buffer.erase(remove(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '*'), buffer.end());

    cout << "The maximum subsequence is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << buffer[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: failed to pass some test cases
`12345898` `2`: `89`, `aEkXxo43E` `4` : `xo4E`, `KeaBe3p3` `3`: `ep3`, `124Kc9s3` `5`: `Kc9s3`
is there anything wrong with my for loop that update vMax?

Comment: As per [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), `a` > `A`, i.e., lower case has higher value than upper case. And also numbers. (`a` > `1`). For example, in the test case `KeaBe3p3`, the answer would be `eep`. How is the right answer ep3?

Comment: @BharatS  I have edited the problem description. It should be much more clearer now.
The maximum subsequence in this question is the largest one (in alphabetical order) of those subsequences with length K.

Answer (score 0):

Reading code which is in one single function is hard. So my advice for the future, split code into smaller pieces.

Instead reading your code I've wrote my solution:

```cpp
using Histogram = std::array<size_t, 128>;

auto makeFullHistogram(const std::string& s)
{
    Histogram r{};
    for (auto ch : s) ++r[ch];
    return r;
}

void clipLeadingValuesOfHistogram(Histogram& hist, size_t len)
{
    for (auto it = hist.rbegin(); it != hist.rend(); ++it) {
        if (len) {
            if (len < *it) {
                *it = len;
            }
            len -= *it;
        } else {
            *it = 0;
        }
    }
}

auto findLeadingValuesHistogram(const std::string& s, size_t len)
{
    auto hist = makeFullHistogram(s);
    clipLeadingValuesOfHistogram(hist, len);
    return hist;
}

std::string bestSubstring(const std::string& s, size_t len)
{
    std::string r;
    r.reserve(len);
    auto hist = findLeadingValuesHistogram(s, len);
    for (auto ch : s) {
        if (hist[ch]) {
            --hist[ch];
            r += ch;

            if (r.size() == len) break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Learning writing tests is also helpful:
https://godbolt.org/z/93aY4aafs